# multiple git subtrees from multiple repos, offsetting the directory layout

Tags: git, git-subtree, sparse-checkout

say I have 2 different git repos:

```
repo-1:
 /dir11
 /dir12
 /dir13

repo-2:
 /dir21
 /dir22
 /dir23
```

so far I only managed the following (with sparsecheckout):

```
work-repo:
  /repo-1
    /dir11
  /repo-2
    /dir22
    /dir23
```

But I'd really like to be able to assemble them in the following fashion:

```
work-repo:
 /dir11
 /dir22
 /dir23
```

and still be able to commit changes in work-repo/dir11 back to repo-1/dir11, ditto for /dir22 and /dir23.

is it possible to achieve such a thing with git-subtree ? (or any other git extension/command)

Comment: yes. on linux and/or darwin. so... symlinks ?

Comment: yes, you guessed it :). There is no better solution to this, unless you want to do something really overly complicated.